# Cannot seem to identify type

Tags: powershell

Modeled on the example in `Get-Help about_Type_Operators`:

```
PS C:\> (get-culture) -is [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]
True
```

I am trying to do just about the same thing with a different type. Why does this fail? I copied the type name from the output of `Get-TypeData`.

(My apologies for the original question using `is` instead of `-is`.)

This suggestion did not work.

```
PS C:\> (Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_BIOS) -is [System.Management.ManagementObject#root\cimv2\Win32_BIOS]
Unable to find type [System.Management.ManagementObject#root\cimv2\Win32_BIOS].
At line:1 char:1
+ (Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_BIOS) -is [System.Management.ManagementOb ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Manageme...imv2\Win32_BIOS:TypeName)
    [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

On a related note, what is the purpose of each of these?

```
PS C:\> Get-TypeData | Where-Object {$_.TypeName -like '*Win32_BIOS' }

TypeName                                                              Members
--------                                                              -------
System.Management.ManagementObject#root\cimv2\Win32_BIOS              {}
Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#root/cimv2/Win32_BIOS {}
```

Comment: Voting to close as a simple typo. Also the basetype of gwmi object in your case is `(Get-WmiObject -Class win32_bios) -is [System.Management.ManagementBaseObject]`

Comment: @Matt - Yes, that works. So, we cannot check to see that it is a Win32_BIOS type as reported by `Get-WmiObject -Class win32_bios | gm`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming...

```
PS> $bios = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_BIOS
```

...you can use the `__CLASS` [system property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa394584.aspx) to test the specific WMI class of an object like this...

```
PS> $bios.__CLASS -eq 'Win32_BIOS'
True
```

...or this...

```
PS> $bios.SystemProperties['__CLASS'].Value -eq 'Win32_BIOS'
True
```

You might also test the namespace just to be *really* sure you've got the right class:

```
PS> $bios.__NAMESPACE -eq 'root\cimv2' -and $bios.__CLASS -eq 'Win32_BIOS'
True
```

Note that the comparisons above don't work exactly like `-is` because you are testing for the exact class, whereas `-is` takes the class hierarchy into account.  That is, the following fails even though `Win32_BIOS` inherits from `CIM_BIOSElement`:

```
PS> $bios.__CLASS -eq 'CIM_BIOSElement'
False
```

The reason why `$bios | Get-Member` shows `System.Management.ManagementObject#root\cimv2\Win32_BIOS` as the type name is because [`Win32_BIOS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa394077.aspx) and its inheritance chain have been added to the [`TypeNames` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.management.automation.psobject.typenames.aspx)...

```
PS> $bios.PSObject.TypeNames
System.Management.ManagementObject#root\cimv2\Win32_BIOS
System.Management.ManagementObject#root\cimv2\CIM_BIOSElement
System.Management.ManagementObject#root\cimv2\CIM_SoftwareElement
System.Management.ManagementObject#root\cimv2\CIM_LogicalElement
System.Management.ManagementObject#root\cimv2\CIM_ManagedSystemElement
System.Management.ManagementObject#Win32_BIOS
System.Management.ManagementObject#CIM_BIOSElement
System.Management.ManagementObject#CIM_SoftwareElement
System.Management.ManagementObject#CIM_LogicalElement
System.Management.ManagementObject#CIM_ManagedSystemElement
System.Management.ManagementObject
System.Management.ManagementBaseObject
System.ComponentModel.Component
System.MarshalByRefObject
System.Object
```

The actual type is still [`ManagementObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.management.managementobject.aspx)...

```
PS> $bios.GetType().FullName
System.Management.ManagementObject
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using the string `is` as the comparison operator; however, all comparison operators begin with the hyphen, so you should be using `-is`: `(Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_BIOS) -is [System.Management.ManagementObject...]`

Comment: This does not seem to work on my system. I have edited the question to include this attempt.

Comment: Your question does not appear to have been edited. **`-is`, not `is`**